# NullPointerException while selecting multiple pages in sites and click on properties AEM

Tags: aem

I am getting NullPointerException as below while selecting multiple pages by navigating to 'sites' and then clicking on properties for all these pages.

```
*ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1514461848712] GET /mnt/overlay/wcm/core/content/sites/properties.html HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl service: Uncaught SlingException java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.jsp.libs.cq.cloudserviceconfigs.components.configurations.configurations_jsp._jspService(configurations_jsp.java:208)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:449)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:346)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:101)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:607)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:388)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:184)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:491)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:552)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:44)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDeveloperModeFilter.doFilter(WCMDeveloperModeFilter.java:133)
    at com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.assetlinkshare.AdhocAssetShareAuthHandler.doFilter(AdhocAssetShareAuthHandler.java:436) 
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
28.12.2017 11:50:49.697 *INFO* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1514461849695] GET /mnt/overlay/wcm/core/content/sites/undefined.infinity.json HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl service: Resource /mnt/overlay/wcm/core/content/sites/undefined.infinity.json not found
```

Not sure what is causing this issue.

Comment: No matter what is causing it, you should open a ticket with Adobe as this appears to be a product issue.

Comment: Indeed, the stack trace does not appear to contain any packages that are not part of the product. It seems we're looking at a product issue rather than a coding problem we could address here. One thing you could try would be to check if any of the pages you're highlighting are somehow broken. Do all of them have their underlying `jcr:content` nodes? Are they of the type `cq:Page`?

Comment: Which version of AEM are you using? Also, from the looks of the stack trace it seems like one or more of the pages are already broken. You might want to check for pages with missing `jcr:content` or pages that are referencing missing cloud service configurations.